# NSOperation for loading image to Cell - crashing

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue

Im using NSOperation to download each cell's image so i don't overload the user with heavy image loading. This works 99% of the times but from time to time i get an nil inside my operation block and the app crash.

This is the code:

```
    cell.blockImage.image = nil
    cell.queue.cancelAllOperations()

    let cacheKey = indexPath.row

    if(self.imagesDictionary.object(forKey: cacheKey) != nil)
    {
        cell.blockImage.image = self.imagesDictionary.object(forKey: cacheKey) as? UIImage
    }
    else
    {
        let operation: BlockOperation = BlockOperation()
        operation.addExecutionBlock({

            if let url = NSURL(string: self.arrJSONData[indexPath.row].image) {
                if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
                    if let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data as Data)
                    {
                        self.imagesDictionary.setObject(image, forKey: cacheKey as NSCopying)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                            if(operation.isCancelled)
                            {
                                return
                            }

                            cell.blockImage.image = image
                        })
                    }
                }
            }



        })

        cell.queue.addOperation(operation)

    }
```

So i download de image and store it in a dictionary. The key is the indexPath.row of the cell.

I also verify if the image is already in the dictionary so i don't download it again.

And i always set my image to nil and cancel the BlockOperation when i start loading the cell.

The error i always get is this:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x608000244c50: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

And i always get it inside this block (but the line is always random)

```
if let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data as Data)
{
    self.imagesDictionary.setObject(image, forKey: cacheKey as NSCopying)
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

        if(operation.isCancelled)
        {
            return
        }

        cell.blockImage.image = image
    })
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you crash but you should consider using something like https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Comment: Im not a fan of external libraries but i should study what this library is doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. If you use `NSMutableDictionary`, you have to synchronize all interactions with that dictionary. `NSMutableDictionary` is not thread-safe. If you use [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscache), which has a very similar interface, it offers thread-safe interaction, so no manual synchronization is needed.
2. Also, you shouldn't just update `cell` inside the operation. You don't know if the cell associated with that index path is still visible or not (or worse, whether it's been reused for some other index path). You should use [`cellForRow(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow) (not to be confused with the similarly named `UITableViewDataSource` method) to get the current cell associated with that `IndexPath`. If that returns a non-`nil` cell reference, should you use that to update the cell's image. If it is `nil`, there is no visible `UIImageView` to update.
3. Unrelated to your crashing, if you scroll quickly through the table view, your queue of network requests can get backlogged downloading images for cells no longer visible. For example, if you scroll quickly to the 100th row, the requests for visible cells can get backlogged behind requests for the first 99 rows that are no longer visible. This problem will be magnified if they have a low-speed network connection (which you should try simulating with the "network link conditioner").

   What makes this even more problematic is that you're using a synchronous, non-cancelable network request. If you, as EricD suggested, used one of the `UIImageView` extensions for asynchronous image retrieval (e.g. [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage), [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher), etc.; there are many out there), this problem could be mitigated.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, i only had time to look today at this issue. Well i ended up using Kingfisher, it saved me a lot of trouble. Thanks, Rob!